# Regular expression split word using number as token

Tags: c++, regex

I want to parse a text and only keep the words with alpha characters or with a `'` character in it (39 in ASCII). For exemple:

```
I know that Dave's car is 'broken'.
```

should be parsed into

```
I/know/that/Dave's/car/is/broken
```

(where `/` is just to show it is another word).

So far, I have:

```
regex e ("\\b[A-Za-z']+\\b");
```

but this does not split `abc2efg` into `abc/efg` which would be the final result I want to get.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what does `\b` imply?

Comment: It matches a word boundary. I don't know if this implementation is the best but for now it can parse the exemple I gave correctly but not two words separated by a number.

Comment: Try `regex e ("\\b[A-Za-z]+(?:'[A-Za-z]+)?\\b");` or, `regex e ("(?:^|[^A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+(?:'[A-Za-z]+)?)(?![A-Za-z])");` and grab Group1 contents

Comment: See https://ideone.com/mi2tgf

Answer (score 0):

`\\b` only matches on word boundaries.

To match words that contain `'` but not words starting or ending with `'` this may work for you. I didn't test it with C++s regex engine.

```
regex e ("([A-Za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z']*[A-Za-z]+)");
```

Comment: With your answer it takes the ' which are in head/tail of the words. For exemple if " 'Hello' " is in a text it will take 'Hello'.

Answer (score 0):

**U can do it**

**#1**

```
(\d+)
```

*Then replace with ', '*

**Result**

abc, def

**#2**

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**Result:**

```
abc
def
```